# C Program to read/write to a file while incrementing numbers in the file

Tags: c, file-io

I am reading a time from a file and then trying to convert the read time to seconds. Is there a simpler way to convert the time stamp? My method seems to be inefficient. What would you suggest be the best method when writing to a file?

Sample File

```
My test file
00:19.1 123456
00:35.4 testing whitespace end

Desired Output
1: My test file
2: 00:19.1
3: 00:35.4
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024                                                                   // define constants, don't use magic number in code
#define MAXN 40
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "";                                                            // buffer to hold each line -- size as reqd
    char filename[MAXN];
    int line = 1;
    int replace_line;
    FILE *fp, *fp2;
    printf("Please enter a file name: ");
    scanf("%s",&filename);
    fp = fopen(filename,"r+");
    if (!fp)                                                                        // validate file open for reading
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    //printf("Enter a increment of time: ");
    //scanf("%d", &increment);
    while (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, fp))                                             // read each line in file
    {
        char et[MAXC] = "";                                                         // buffer for holding time
        char etR[MAXC] = "";
        char time[7] = "";
        int filler = 0;

        if (line == 1)                                                              // if 1st line, just print
        {
            printf ("%d : %s", line, buf);                                          // note: \n included by fgets
            //fprintf(fp2,"%s",buf);
        }   // end of if first line
        else
        {
            if (sscanf (buf, "%s", et) != 1)                                        // parse up to first whitespace
            {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid conversion, line %d\n", line);
                return 1;
            }
            printf ("%d : %s\n", line, et);                                         //output elapsed time only
            while(filler < 7)
            {
                time[filler] = et[filler];
                filler++;
            }
            time[1] = time[1] - '0';    //Leading Minute (error if over 6)
            time[2] = time[2] - '0';    //Minute
            time[4] = time[4] - '0';    //Leading Second (Add to minute if over 6)
            time[5] = time[5] - '0';    //Second (Add to LS if over 9)
            time[7] = time[7] - '0';    //fraction of a second (Add to S if over 9)
            float timeInSeconds;
            char minuteHolder[2];
            sprintf(minuteHolder,"%d%d",time[1],time[2]);
            int minute;
            minute = (minuteHolder[0]*10) + minuteHolder[1];
            printf("\n%d\n",minute);
            //getting 539 , minutes on every line???

        }   //end of else
        line++;                                                                     // increment line count
    }   // end of while parsing file
    rewind(fp);
    if (fp != stdin)                                                                // close file if not stdin
    {
        fclose (fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Exact Duplicate of [**Simple C program to read a file line by line**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003514/simple-c-program-to-read-a-file-line-by-line) (I know, I answered)

Answer (score 0):

convert source string: "00:19.1 123456"
to dest string： "1. 00:19.1"

- 1st : we should find the black character pos:
       *char *pblack = strchr(buf, ' ');*
       now pblack is point to " 123456".
- 2nd: we set the old string to the new string:
       becase a string is endwith '\0',
       so we set: *pblack[0] = '\0';*

now , we have the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024                                                                   // define constants, don't use magic number in code
#define MAXN 40
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

char buf[MAXC] = "";                                                            // buffer to hold each line -- size as reqd
char filename[MAXN];
int line = 1;
int replace_line;
//FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
//FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt","r");
FILE *fp, *fp2;
printf("Please enter a file name: ");
scanf("%s", &filename);
fp = fopen(filename, "r+");
//fp2 = fopen("datadump.txt","w");
if (!fp)                                                                        // validate file open for reading
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
    return 1;
}
//printf("Enter a increment of time: ");
//scanf("%d", &increment);
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp))                                             // read each line in file
{
    char et[MAXC] = "";                                                         // buffer for holding time
    char etR[MAXC] = "";
    char time[7] = "";
    int filler = 0;

    if (line == 1)                                                              // if 1st line, just print
    {
        printf("%d : %s", line, buf);                                          // note: \n included by fgets
                                                                               //fprintf(fp2,"%s",buf);
    }   // end of if first line
    else
    {
        char *pblack = strchr(buf, ' '); // get chr ' ' pos
        pblack[0] = 0;                   // set ' ' to '\0', get the new string 
        printf("%d : %s\n", line, buf);
    }   //end of else
    line++;                                                                     // increment line count
}   // end of while parsing file
rewind(fp);
//fp2 = fopen("replica.c","w");
//replacement code
/*
flcose(fp);
fclose(fp2);
remove(filename(;
rename("replica.c",filename);
//if you to show them new file fflush stdin and repeat while
//fp = fopen(filename, "r");
//while loop
*/
if (fp != stdin)                                                                // close file if not stdin
{
    fclose(fp);
    //fclose (fp2);
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If the time format is the **same** after the incremental, you can replace the time field with `fseek` without rewriting the whole file.
An overall example is shown. Please change details.
try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXC    1024 //input buffer size
#define MAXLINE 1024 //max number of line

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    char filename[FILENAME_MAX+1+1];//+1: newline, +1: NUL
    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    char time_field[7+1];//mm:ss.s, +1: NUL
    unsigned char ch;
    long pos[MAXLINE];//save file positions
    int line = 0;     //start with 0 in program
    int replace_line; //input replace line number
    int increment;    //input incremant second.
    FILE *fp;

    printf("Please enter a file name: ");
    fgets(filename, sizeof filename, stdin);
    filename[strcspn(filename, "\n")] = 0;//chomp newline
    fp = fopen(filename, "r+");
    if (!fp){
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }
    //display file & store file position each line
    pos[line] = ftell(fp);
    while (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, fp)){
        if(++line == MAXLINE){
            fprintf (stderr, "error: file too long.\n");//Need change the program. expand array or use malloc and realloc
            return 2;
        }
        pos[line] = ftell(fp);
        if (!isdigit(ch = *buf)){//If it does not start with a numerical value Output as it is
            printf("%d : %s", line, buf);  //note: \n included by fgets
        } else {
            if(sscanf(buf, "%7s%c", time_field, &ch)==2 && isspace(ch)){
                printf ("%d : %s\n", line, time_field);
            } else {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid time format '%s'", buf);
                return 3;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Enter a number of edit line: ");
    scanf("%d", &replace_line);

    printf("Enter a increment of time: ");
    scanf("%d", &increment);//sec

    if(fseek(fp, pos[replace_line-1], SEEK_SET)==0){//-1: 0 start in program, 1 start in input
        int m, s, ds, seconds;
        fscanf(fp, "%s", time_field);
        if(sscanf(time_field, "%d:%d.%d", &m, &s, &ds)!=3){
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid time format '%s' at %d line.\n", time_field, replace_line);
            return 3;
        }
        seconds = m * 60 + s + increment;
        m = seconds / 60;
        s = seconds % 60;
        if(m > 99 || seconds < 0){
            fprintf (stderr, "error: Can't change time format.\n");//It is necessary to rewrite the whole file.
            return 4;
        }
        fseek(fp, pos[replace_line-1], SEEK_SET);
        fprintf(fp, "%02d:%02d", m, s);fflush(fp);
    } else {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file seek failed to '%d' line.\n", replace_line);
        return 5;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have changed and extended this code for my application, one remaining question I have is what would be a good way to fix this issue I am having.

Issue: (variable/10.0) for instance (9/10.0) returns .8999

How can I make it (9/10.0) = .9?

Comment: Are you saying the variable should be a float?
Example: (9.0/10.0) would result in .9?

Comment: @Collin No. Use `int`. E.g `00:19.1` ==> `191`,  `191` ==> `printf("%d.%d", 191/10, 191 % 10)` ==>  `19.1`

Comment: Okay I understand now, thank you. Can you explain one last thing for me.

sscanf(time_field, "%d:%d.%d", &m, &s, &ds)!=3

can you explain the !=3? I understand this would result in an invalid time format but what are checking to 3?

Comment: @Collin The `scanf` family returns the number of elements that could be read. In this case, `3` is returned if three items(`m`, `s` and `ds`) can be read, otherwise it is a number other than `3`.